# INSERT FROM EXISTING SELECT without amending

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

With GDPR in the UK on the looming horizon and already have a team of 15 users creating spurious SELECT statements (in excess of 2,000) across 15 differing databases I need to be able to create a method to capture an already created SELECT statement and be able to assign surrogate keys/data WITHOUT rewriting every procedure we already have.

There will be a need to run the original team members script as normal and there will be requirements to pseudo the values.

My current thinking is to create a stored procedure along the lines of:

```
CREATE PROC Pseudo (@query NVARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT INTO #TEMP FROM @query
```

Do something with the data via a mapping table of real and surrogate/pseudo data.

```
UPDATE #TEMP
SET FNAME = (SELECT Pseudo_FNAME FROM PseudoTable PT WHERE #TEMP.FNAME = PT.FNAME)
SELECT * FROM #TEMP
```

So that team members can run their normal `SELECT` statements and get pseudo data simply by using:

```
 EXEC Pseudo (SELECT FNAME FROM CUSTOMERS)
```

The problem I'm having is you can't use:

```
INSERT INTO #TEMP FROM @query
```

So I tried via CTE:

```
WITH TEMP AS (@query)
```

..but I can't use that either.

Surely there's a way of capturing the recordset from an existing select that I can pull into a table to amend it or capture the `SELECT` statement; without having to amend the original script. Please bear in mind that each `SELECT` statement will be unique so I can't write COLUMN or `VALUES` etc.

Does any anyone have any ideas or a working example(s) on how to best tackle this?

There are other lengthy methods I could externally do to carry this out  but I'm trying to resolve this within SQL if possible.

Answer (score 0):

So after a bit of deliberation I resolved it.
I passed the Original SELECT SQL to SP that used some SQL Injection, which when executed INSERTed data. I then Updated from that dataset.

The end result was "EXEC Pseudo(' Orginal SQL ;')
I will have to set some basic rules around certain columns for now as a short term fix..but at least users can create NonPseudo and Pseudo data as required without masses of reworking :)